# group by sum and join giving duplicate rows

Tags: hive

I have a table where I have materialno, billedqty, materialdesc, startdate columns.
I need to find the sum of billedqty for each materialno. This giving me duplicate values(I need distinct materialno and sum of billedqty). This is the query I have written using group by and join.I want to group by materialno only because by other columns i am getting wrong sum values.

```
create table test1(
materialno string,
BilledQtysum Double)
stored as ORCFILE;

insert into table test1
select materialno,sum(BilledQty) from billing group by materialno;

select s1.MaterialNo,s1.Material_Description,s1.BilledQty,s2.BilledQtysum,s1.Start_Date
 from test1 s2 join billing s1 on s2.materialno=s1.materialno;
```

```
Billing Table:
 materailno billedqty materaildesc startdate
 1001      |    22   |  materail1 |2017-05-23
 1002      |    25   |  materail2 |2012-04-29
 1003      |    30   | materail2  |2013-02-03
 1001      |    22   | materail2  |2013-02-03

 Expected Result:
   materailno billedqty materaildesc startdate
 1001      |    44   |  materail1 |2017-05-23
 1002      |    25   |  materail2 |2012-04-29
 1003      |    30   | materail2  |2013-02-03

   my result:
 materailno billedqty materaildesc startdate
 1001      |    44   |  materail1 |2017-05-23
 1002      |    25   |  materail2 |2012-04-29
 1003      |    30   | materail2  |2013-02-03
 1001      |    44   | materail2  |2013-02-03
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: I'm not seeing any group by or sum in your final query.  Nor am I seeing anything in your desired result that looks like a sum.  Based on what you put for your desired result, you simply want to group by all 4 columns.

Comment: I dont want to group by all 4 columns. only by materialno so i group by materialno and join those to my table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting duplicates due to join, you can get expected results without join. Try below query

```
select materialno, sum(billedqty), min(materialdesc), min(startdate) from billing group by materialno;
```

When you are joining **test1** with **billing** table, you are getting duplicates because your materialno="1001" is having 2 corresponding "**materialdesc**" values, and "**startdate**" values. But the query I mentioned returns only first "**materialdesc**" and "**startdate**" of "**materialno**".